# How do you make textbox sizes adjust for more characters?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a text field I'm using get bigger when you add more characters to it, is there any way to do this?
I suprisingly haven't found a way to do this through searching.
For example:

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="John" size="1">
```

Would turn into

```html
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="John Smith" size="4">
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="fname" size="1" onkeypress="this.style.minWidth = ((this.value.length + 3) * 7) + 'px';">`

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the `<input>` element into a `<textarea>`, then state how many rows and columns you want to have (basically height and width). In addition, the user can adjust it from there! If you're taking form data, it will still be able to be read. Just make sure that when you make the change remove the `size=""`

Answer (score 0):

its should be adjusted when you enter more characters.

```html
<input type="text" name="FirstName" onkeypress="this.style.minWidth = ((this.value.length + 1) * 7) + 'px';">
```

Comment: I did comment on his question an edited version of the same trick. I think its more accurate.

Comment: I think we post the same time. Thanks

Comment: it's ok. I meant you can use that to update the answer if you want. good luck.